# Show details on ALL cells of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells

I am trying to achieve an effect that when detail button is pressed, details will slide in to ALL cells of tableView. So far I have achieved this trough iterating through the visible cells of the table view. Each cell has a detail label that is off screen that slides in with animation. This is how it looks:

- Before Detail Button Pressed

[image: Before Detail Button Pressed]

- After detail button pressed
  [image: After detail button pressed]

Of cours since I am iterating through the visible cells, the cells at the bottom dont have the details when scrolling down after having pressed the detail button. I am aware of the fact that the cells that are not shown on screen is not in memory, but maybe there is an another approach to this?

**EDIT**
Here is the code that executes when user presses "Details" button

```
let animationDuration = 0.4
    for cell in myTableView.visibleCells {
        let cell = cell as! MainCell

        if !detailView {
            sender.tintColor = UIColor.gray
            detailView = true

            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: ({
                cell.noteLbl.center.x = cell.noteLbl.center.x + 100
            }))
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: ({
                cell.accessoryLbl.center.x = cell.accessoryLbl.center.x + 100
            }))
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: ({
                cell.timeLbl.center.x = cell.timeLbl.center.x + 100
            }))
        } else {
            detailView = false
            sender.tintColor = UIColor.white

            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: ({
                cell.noteLbl.center.x = cell.noteLbl.center.x - 100
            }))
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: ({
                cell.accessoryLbl.center.x = cell.accessoryLbl.center.x - 100
            }))
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: ({
                cell.timeLbl.center.x = cell.timeLbl.center.x - 100
            }))
        }

    }
```

Code for the cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell") as! MainCell
    let shiftForRow = shifts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.noteLbl.text = shiftForRow.note
    cell.dateLbl.text = shiftForRow.date
    cell.accessoryLbl.text = calcTotalHours(STField: shiftForRow.startingTime!, ETField: shiftForRow.endingTime!, lunchTime: shiftForRow.lunchTime!)
    cell.timeLbl.text = shiftForRow.startingTime! + " - " + shiftForRow.endingTime!

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two screen shots, and it is not clear what "all cells" can even mean.

Comment: @matt I updated the post so both screenshots are visible(thanks for suggestion). The cells on the second screen shot has the details on them to the left. By all cells I mean that when the button is pressed, all cells should show the details even those that appear when scrolling down.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include relevant code. But clearly you have not properly implemented your `cellForRowAt` to show the proper cell details based on the current mode.

Comment: @rmaddy Edited the post with code. I just thought it wasn't neccessary in this question.

Comment: And where's your `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: @rmaddy Added it. My point was, I dont do anything special in the cellForRowAt. I lay them out and then I want to iterate over all those cells, maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you scroll a table view (and when initially displayed), the `cellForRowAt` method is called for each cell that needs to be displayed.

At the moment your `cellForRowAt` only shows your cells in their "normal" layout as if the detail button has never been pressed. You need to update your `cellForRowAt` method so it configures the cell based on whether details should be shown or not.

You probably need a flag to track whether details are currently being shown or not. Toggle that flag based on the detail button being pressed.

Then, based on that state of that flag, your `cellForRowAt` method needs to setup the cell appropriately.